# certbot-auto fails with error message ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref

Tags: certbot

After Debian upgrade `certbot-auto` fails with an error message

```
Error: couldn't get currently installed version for /opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/letsencrypt: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/letsencrypt", line 7, in <module>
    from certbot.main import main
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import logging.handlers
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

What shall I do?

Answer (score 2):

Just try to remove the installation by

```
# rm -r /opt/eff.org
```

and run `certbot-auto` again. This should reinstall the virtualenv.